# Android Widget with listview gets resizable on single tap

Tags: android, android-widget, android-remoteview

I have created a widget which has a `listview` with multiple click actions on each single item of it. Everything works fine, but just on normal single tap anywhere over the empty area of the `widget` makes the `widget` editable, which is not an usual behavior (actual behavior: long press on the widget is the action to make the widget editable).

I have no clue why this is happening. Please drive me in the right direction.

Comment: can you post your code?

Comment: Found the problem. It was happening only with google pixel launcher. When I tap over the empty area of the widget which has NO onclickevent to it, makes the widget resizable.